# Flecha através do css

Tags: css, ionic

Bom galera, tô começando com o ionic e ao tentar reproduzir algumas telas me deparei com uma flecha, isso mesmo, uma flecha, segue a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que tenho até agora:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E de código:

```
<ion-content>

  <div id="container">

    <ion-item lines="full" class="ion-no-padding">
      <ion-input placeholder="MY NAME IS"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item mode="ios" lines="none" class="ion-no-padding" id="x">
      <ion-input id="item-custom" placeholder="GET ACCESS" [type]="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

  </div>

</ion-content>
```

A questão é como reproduzir essa flecha, qual seria a melhor solução ? Pensei em utilizar o ion-icon mas só consigo aumentar ela como um todo utilizando

```
font-size: ;
```

e não uma única dimensão, correto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui tem uma sugestão só com CSS, pode te ajudar, mas basicamente é um elemento simples com um *pseudo-elemento* que é um quadrado só com `2 bordas` e girado `45deg`

Vc pode ajustar os valor em px para ficar do tamanho que achar adequado...

```css
seta {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: orangered;
  margin: 20px 10px;
}
seta::after {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0 solid orangered;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 2px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<seta></seta>
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso, fera demais !

Comment: @AfonsodeOliveira legal que deu certo ai! Fico feliz em ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

```css
.arrow { background: #000; height: 1px; width: 180px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; cursor: pointer;}
.arrow:before, .arrow:after { content: ""; background: #000; position: absolute;
  height: 1px; width: 15px;
}
.arrow:before { right: -5px; bottom: -5px; transform: rotate(-45deg); }
.arrow:after { right: -5px; top: -5px; transform: rotate(45deg);}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: É legal [citar a fonte](https://www.csscodelab.com/css-checkbox-arrow-keyframes-animation/) sempre que você pega a sua resposta de outro lugar, mesmo que seja só uma parte ou uma referência. Além disso, uma explicação do código ajudará tanto o OP quanto qualquer visitante futuro que queira **aprender** ao invés de apenas copiar.